# Rendering Custom Fonts Using MonoTouch & CoreGraphics

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, core-graphics

I need to be able to draw custom fonts in CGContext but when I change how I select a font, the font is not shown.

```
//Works
    protected void DrawCenteredTextAtPoint(CGContext context, float centerX, float y, string text, int textHeight)
    {
        context.SelectFont("Helvetica-Bold", textHeight, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
        context.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Invisible);
        context.ShowTextAtPoint(centerX, y, text, text.Length);
        context.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);
        context.ShowTextAtPoint(centerX - (context.TextPosition.X - centerX)/2, y, text, text.Length);
    }

//Does not work
protected void DrawCenteredTextAtPoint(CGContext context, float centerX, float y, string text, int textHeight)
{
    var fontPath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("COOPBL", "ttf", "fonts", "");
    var provider = new CGDataProvider(fontPath);
    var font = CGFont.CreateFromProvider(provider);
    context.SetFont(font);
    context.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Invisible);
    context.ShowTextAtPoint(centerX, y, text, text.Length);
    context.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);
    context.ShowTextAtPoint(centerX - (context.TextPosition.X - centerX)/2, y, text, text.Length);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use your custom font in simpler places? For example, call `UILabel.Font = UIFont.FromName(fn, 17);`, where fn = "COOPBL". I'm asking cause when you add font to cproj-file in Xamarin Studio, it doesn't marks as Content in Build Action. So, maybe font is not correctly included to project.

Answer (score 0):

That works:

```cs
    protected void DrawCenteredTextAtPoint(CGContext context, float centerX, float y, string text, int textHeight)
    {
        //          var fontPath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("COOPBL", "ttf", "fonts", "");
        //          var provider = new CGDataProvider(fontPath);
        //          var font = CGFont.CreateFromProvider(provider);

        //context.SelectFont("Helvetica-Bold", textHeight, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
        //var cgFont = CGFont.CreateWithFontName("Cooper Black");
        //context.SetFont(cgFont);

        context.SelectFont("Cooper Black", textHeight, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);

        context.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Invisible);
        context.ShowTextAtPoint(centerX, y, text, text.Length);
        context.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);
        context.ShowTextAtPoint(centerX - (context.TextPosition.X - centerX)/2, y, text, text.Length);
    }
```

How I use it

```
...

public class CustomView: UIView
{
    public CustomView ()
    {
    }

    public override void Draw (System.Drawing.RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw (rect);

        var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
        DrawCenteredTextAtPoint(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext(), 50, 10, "adsasdasd", 20);
    }

...

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        v = new CustomView();
        v.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        View.AddSubview(v);
        v.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 100, 320, 100);

...
```

How it looks like with `Cooper Black` font:

[image]

Please note that you should correctly add a font to project:

- Add font file reference to cproj-file;
- Mark font file as `Content` in `Build Action`;
- Add font file reference to [Info.plist file](http://fastchicken.co.nz/uploads/2012/09/info-plist-settings.png).

Notes: http://fastchicken.co.nz/2012/09/07/using-fonts-in-a-monotouch-app/.